# Как убрать 're.Match object..' из строки вывода?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

ищу слово в строке регуляркой

```
str0 = r'хххх хххххххх Х. ххх ХХХ хххх 7б-206'
room = (re.search(r'[0-9]{1,2}[а-я]{1}-[0-9]*[а-я]*', str0))
print(room)
```

Результат: `<re.Match object; span=(41, 47), match='7б-206'>`

Можно ли получить чистое значение '7б-206'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
str0 = r'хххх хххххххх Х. ххх ХХХ хххх 7б-206'
room = (re.search(r'[0-9]{1,2}[а-я]{1}-[0-9]*[а-я]*', str0))
print(room.group(0))
```

Результат:

```
7б-206
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!